# Make media key control only one app

Tags: itunes, keyboard, mediaplayer

I want to use my media keys exclusively for Spotify.
Currently, media keys have undefined behaviour - sometimes they control to most recent active media app (vlc, youtube), sometimes they control two apps together. They are just behaving weirdly. I only need media keys for one app (spotify), so I guess there must be a simple solution. Is there?